# fullcalendar not showing even when updating files

Tags: fullcalendar

I have updated the files as per instructions from fullcalendar.io documentation but the calendar isn't showing.

Files
[image: Files]

No Calendar
[image: No Calendar]

I am unsure where to put this code in the php files:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
    });
    
    calendar.render();
});
```

Am very new to this so please bear with me. Thanks

Comment: What version of fullCalendar are you using? Are there any errors in your browser's console? Also open the browser's network tool while loading the page and watch for the CSS and js files being loaded and check they don't show any errors - they should load with a "200" status if it succeeded.

Comment: `I am unsure where to put this code in the php files`...it's JavaScript code so it goes inside a `<script>` block on the page where you want the calendar to appear. P.s. If you've never used JavaScript before then I'd suggest a fairly heavyweight and complex calendar library is not the place to start learning it

Comment: Ok. Well you need to put it in a script tag as I mentioned. Have you made any kind of attempt to do that?

Comment: Version is 5.7.2. Everything loads with 200 status but I'm getting an error saying `a(...).fullCalendar is not a function`. It's from a plugin I have forked and inherited and saw they use fullcalendar but needed an update due to all the deprecated function

Comment: That sounds like an error from a different bit of the code than what you've shown. It sounds like there is still some code trying to load an older version of fullCalendar